# Java Unsupported Locale (JCalendar)

Tags: java, swing, localization, jcalendar

I'm developing a desktop application with Swing for an unsupported language.

I have my own properties file. I'm using it for the messages in the application. I also call `setLocale()` method of the `JCalendar` with my file. But since I don't know which keywords to use for months, month selection inside the `JCalendar` shows English named months.

For example, I tried:

```
january=translatedJanuary
february=translatedFebruary
```

I couldn't find a tutorial or form to fill to create a locale (properties) file. Is there one? Or is it still impossible for `JCalendar` to get words from properties file. Or simply, what is the necessary keywords?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of the [initNames() method in JCalendar's JMonthChooser class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.toedter/jcalendar/1.4/com/toedter/calendar/JMonthChooser.java#JMonthChooser.initNames%28%29), we see:

```
DateFormatSymbols dateFormatSymbols = new DateFormatSymbols(locale);
String[] monthNames = dateFormatSymbols.getMonths();
```

So, you can't override the names with your own ResourceBundle entries.  The best you can do is hope that Java SE defines month names for the locale you pass to `setLocale`.